# BB10 Webworks packaging Interrupted (aborting) error

Tags: packaging, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, ripple, sencha-touch-2.2

I am trying to build a BB10 webworks app using Sencha Touch 2.2 and packaging using Ripple and keep getting Interrupted (aborting) errors. Is anyone else seeing this? I have noticed that I am able to clear this error if the `.sass_cache` fills up under `/resources/sass` folder of the Sencha Touch project.

```
out:  (deflated 71%)
  adding: touch/src/XTemplateCompiler.js (deflated 72%)
  adding: touch/src/XTemplateParser.js (deflated 76%)
  adding: touch/version.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: twitter_bb.js (deflated 61%)
  adding: webworks-1.0.4.11.js
out: 


out: 
zip error: Interrupted (aborting)

error response - {"code":1,"msg":"\nzip error: Interrupted (aborting)\n","data":null}
2013-06-13 11:48:44 GET /ripple/build_status/1021 200
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying various things, I ran into the solution, by sheer luck I suppose. When compiling a Sencha Touch app, it compiles the sass file and creates a cache. Sencha Touch doesn't clear the `.sass_cache` folder after it's done compiling. This seemed to be causing odd issues with the package operation for a BB10 webworks app. It would stop with the message above on zipping different files.

After removing all the contents of the `.sass_cache` folder using `rm -rvf *` I was able to get it to successfully package.